# Pomeranchuk Effect

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, phase-transition, low-temperature-physics, fermi-liquids

Pomeranchuk effect poses a paradox of order by disorder phase-transition. The liquid Helium-3 is in a liquid form close to absolute temperature. For high enough pressure, as you increase the temperature, it becomes Solid and stays as a solid for a range of temperatures. This effect is attributed to the fact that in the solid phase, there is an enormous entropy contribution coming from the nuclear spins (See ref. https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1996/richardson/lecture/)

I was wondering why there is no nuclear-spin entropy contribution in the liquid phase itself?